# Terminology - What pod means?

Tags: terminology

I read some papers with the term *pod*. Specially "*pod switches*". What *pod* means? This is an acronym? To what?

Comment: Is this in relation to a class or training? When I've run across that term it refers to a set of switches, servers, etc. (usually virtual and in the cloud) set up for each student. So your pod is yours to use and experiment with during the class or lab time.

Comment: Perhaps you mean [PoD- Point of Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_delivery_(networking)), which is a modular design pattern used in data center network fabrics?

Comment: @Jedi and RSS thanks for your comments. The term was in this paper: http://ccr.sigcomm.org/online/files/p63-alfares.pdf. I think is a set of devices, but don't know the literal meaning of pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the provided context, you are referring to [leiserson1985fat](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6312192).

[image: k-ary fat tree]

Here a pod has (K/2)^2 servers and 2 layers of K/2 K-port switches.
[Source](https://www.slideshare.net/AnkitaMahajan2/fattree-a-scalable-fauult-tolerant)

Comment: ok, but pod means what? Point of delivery? Point of distribution? Point of devices? Is not an acronym? Do you know?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is a Point-of-Delivery module.

Comment: I don't know for sure but my assumption was that it was just the normal english word "pod" and was being used to reffer to a physically grouped set of equipment.

Answer (score 0):

These days, pod tends to refer widely to the [unit of Kubernetes deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/).

The nomenclature is inspired by the [collective noun for whales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal#W). A pod refers to a group of one or more containers (typically Docker containers, represented by a whale) that can share storage mounts, network port space and scheduling lifetime.